# How many combinations can be made for the fraction?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Rational numbers, $a, b$ are chosen from the set of rational numbers. The condition is: $a, b \in [0, 2)$. $a, b$ can be written as: $a, b = \frac{n}{d}$, where $n, d$ are integers with: $1 \le d \le 5$.

How many values are there for $a, b$?

I took in deep consideration, $a, b \in [0, 2)$.

$$\text{Number of ways d can be chosen:} \space \binom{5}{1} = 5$$

Since:

$$0 \le \frac{n}{d} < 2 \implies 0 \le n < 2d \implies 0 \le n < 10$$

Which shows there are:

$$11 \space \text{ways to get n}$$

The answer should be (for $a$):

$$11 \cdot 5 = 55$$

But it is supposed to be $20$?

Comment: Some numbers have been counted more than once. E.g. $0$ is counted $5$ times and $\frac12=\frac24$ is counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the number of choices you have for $n$ depends on the value of $d$! And we have doublets, for example $\frac 24 = \frac 12$. I think the easiest way is to enumerate all possibilities:

- $d=1$: $n = 0,1$,
- $d=2$: $n = 1,3$ ($n=0,2$ have allready been counted for $d = 1$)
- $d=3$: $n = 1,2,4,5$,
- $d=4$: $n = 1,3,5,7$,
- $d=5$: $n = 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9$

so 20 possibilites.